# stylePreprocessorOptions->includePaths ignored if I use scss @use instead of @import in Angular 12.1 component styles (nx)

Tags: angular, sass, nrwl-nx

I have NX workspace with Angular 12.1

And in workspace.json there is
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
"includePaths": [
"apps/my-app/src/styles",
]

This folder contains variables.scss

I want to import variables.scss in some.component.scss

If I use @import - it works fine with defining where file is located

@import 'variables';

but if I want to use @use  I have to specify full path

@use 'apps/my-app/src/styles/variables' as *;

How to make it understand includePaths with @use as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that could be the case here, but for me nx migration set incorrect paths for `includePaths` - kept the original values without prepending the new longer path (`apps/etc`) in the app's `project.json`. Interestingly, the paths for `assets` and `styles` were set correctly.
After updating `includePaths`, both `@use` and `@import` work.